# How to implement the small arrow at a twitter bootstrap subnav' dropdown

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, pseudo-class

I've successfully implemented a dropdown menu at bootstrap 'subnav' (taken from docs.css) using a modal.

The issue is the little arrow (**not the caret, but the WHITE arrow** that 'connects' the div/modal with the link.).

I managed to get the arrow rendered(using ':after'), but couldn't understand how to hide/toggle it , as it works in the standard navbar dropdown.

Don't care about the positioning of the modal (It looks as expected using fiddle 'show').

The fiddle(show): http://jsfiddle.net/MDtCg/5/show/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Two simple CSS updates should do it:

```
a strong.caret {
 display: none;   
}

a:hover strong.caret {
 display: inline-block;   
}
```

Comment: clarification: I don't mean the caret, but the WHITE arrow that 'connects' the div/modal with the link. Thanks anyway

Comment: you mean the arrow next to "click here" or the arrow of the box appearing when clicking "click here"? :-)

Comment: I meant the arrow of the box appearing when clicking "click here". Please check the message you see at the box. It should now be clearer. Thanks!